# how to configure postfix,dovecot mail server to save log in MySQL

Tags: mysql, postfix-mta, dovecot

I want to have the log of sender-name,receiver-name and deliver time in my SQL
but I don't have any idea that I should configure postfix or dovecot for that
and how to configure them
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward and non-intrusive way is to pass all the messages to the `syslog`. That functionality is already built-in for both `postfix` and `dovecot`. Say for `dovecot` configuration should look like that:

```
. . . .
log_path        = syslog
syslog_facility = mail
. . . .
```

`syslog` can direct all the messages received from the certain binary to the pipe.

```
mail.*     |/tmp/maillog.pipe
```

Then some script should read that pipe, parse lines and invoke the CLI mysql client that store the data into the database.

```
#!/bin/sh
while read LINE
do 
   # all the parsing should be written here
   mysql -e "USE maillog; INSERT INTO $table VALUES ($a, $b, $c);" 
   # any additional proceeding can be performed here
done < /tmp/maillog.pipe
####
```

All that isn't a working solution but just a hint. Exact configuration and script code depend on your actual needs.

Comment: what exactly i want is to have this log(sender,receiver,deliver time)  in mysql to use in asp.net and i think the first step is to configure one of this two(postfix dovecot)
just trying to figure out a simple way to have this report in my asp mvc application